# route group slim framework

Tags: php, routes, slim

I want to create a ¨dynamic¨ route group in Slim framework but I´m getting

**Warning: Missing argument 1 for {closure}() i**

this is my code:

```
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->group('/:segment1/:segment2', function ($segment1, $segment2) use ($app) {

    $app->map('/', function () use ($app) {

    })->via('GET', 'POST');

    $app->map('/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {

    })->via('GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE');

});

$app->run();
```

If i change:

```
$app->group('/:segment1/:segment2', function ($segment1, $segment2) use ($app)
```

to:

```
$app->group('/segment1/segment2', function () use ($app)
```

it starts working but I need those segments to be dynamic. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add group parameters to their child routes function:

```php
$app->group('/:segment1/:segment2', function () use ($app) {

    $app->map('/', function ($segment1, $segment2) use ($app) {
        // something
    })->via('GET', 'POST');

    $app->map('/:id', function ($segment1, $segment2, $id) use ($app) {
        // something
    })->via('GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE');
});
```

Also look at [this issue](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/926).

Comment: just to confirm I will not be able to use $segment1 and $segment2 inside the group (I need to create an object there and use it inside those to $app->map() thanks!